# Receber o valor de uma variável de um input e comparar com uma predefinida pra gerar um alert e redirecionar

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-hooks

Bom dia, eu sou novo com React Native e estou tentando comparar o valor de uma variável que recebi através de um Textinput com uma já predefinida para gerar um alert e me redirecionar pra outra screen, só que não consigo fazer as comparações funcionar e muito menos a variavel receber o valor para pular de tela ou não, poderiam me dar uma força?

Peguei o return pra retomar o valor, mas não consigo comparar as variávels login-login1 e senha-senha1 nele.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Sucess } from './src/screens/Sucess';
import { Denied } from './src/screens/Denied';

export default function App(){

  const [login1,setlogin1] = useState('');
  const [senha1,setsenha1] = useState('');

  const ConfereSenha = () => {
    let login = "test";
    let senha = "1234";

    return(
      if(login1 != login && senha1 != senha){
        alert("Senha incorreta")
        <Denied />
      } else {
        alert("Acesso liberado")
        <Sucess />
      })
  }

<TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder='Login' onChangeText={(login1)=>setlogin1(login1)} maxLength={10}></TextInput>

<TextInput secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(senha1)=>setsenha1(senha1)} maxLength={10}

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.botaolog} onPress={ConfereSenha}>ENTRAR</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Eder, tudo bem? No react a expressão:

```js
return(
  if(login1 != login && senha1 != senha){
    alert("Senha incorreta")
    <Denied />
  } else {
    alert("Acesso liberado")
    <Sucess />
  }
)
```

É incorreta. Acredito que você esteja utilizando JSX, então você poderia fazer

```js
if(login1 != login && senha1 != senha){
  alert("Senha incorreta")
} else {
  alert("Acesso liberado")
}

return(
  {login1 != login && senha1 != senha ? <Denied /> : <Sucess />}
)
```

Estes 3 elementos devem estar dentro do retorno do render do componente App também.

```js
<TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder='Login' onChangeText={(login1)=>setlogin1(login1)} maxLength={10}></TextInput>

<TextInput secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(senha1)=>setsenha1(senha1)} maxLength={10}

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.botaolog} onPress={ConfereSenha}>ENTRAR</TouchableOpacity>
```

Entretanto, mesmo com as correções, não irá funcionar da maneira que você espera. Seu código possui um conjunto de outros erros. Te aconselharia a olhar a documentação do [React](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react) de forma que você conseguisse corrigir os erros de  lógica e JSX.